# Networking Layer in Swift , Completion Blocks and Errors

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing a Networking Layer in Swift. Here is one of the functions. The function works as expected but I want to improve upon it. I am using DispatchQueue to make sure that the callback from the network client is always on the main thread. This ends up repeating the DispatchQueue.main.async in 3 different places.

Also, when I encounter some error when performing the request I still send back nil but as a success.

```
func getAllStocks(url: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Stock]?,NetworkError>) -> Void) {

    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        completion(.failure(.invalidURL)) // wrap in DispatchQueue also 
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.success(nil)) // should I send nil or some sort of failure
            }

            return
        }

        let stocks = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Stock].self, from: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(.success(stocks))
        }

    }

}
```

How can I minimize the code or is it fine?

Comment: try CodyFire lib

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the `Result` type is that you return a **non**-optional type on success and an error on failure.

I recommend to call `completion` on the current thread and dispatch the result on the caller side.

And handle also the `DecodingError`

```
func getAllStocks(url: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Stock],Error>) -> Void) {

    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        completion(.failure(NetworkError.invalidURL)) 
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

        if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)); return }          
        // if error is nil then data has a value
        do {
            let stocks = try JSONDecoder().decode([Stock].self, from: data!)
            completion(.success(stocks))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }.resume()  
}
```

---

```
getAllStocks(url: someURL) { result in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        switch result {
            case .success(let stocks): print(stocks)
            case .failure(let networkError as NetworkError): handleNetworkError(networkError)
            case .failure(let decodingError as DecodingError): handleDecodingError(decodingError)
            case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much nicer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lean into the build-in constructs and standard types.

```swift
func getAllStocks(url: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Stock], Error>) -> Void) {
    func completeOnMain(_ result: Result<[Stock], Error>) { // <-- Nested function
        DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(result) } // <-- Handle repeated work
    }

    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        completeOnMain(.failure(URLError(.badURL))) // <-- Standard Error
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        do {
            if let error = error { throw error }
            guard let data = data else { throw URLError(.badServerResponse) }

            let stocks = try JSONDecoder().decode([Stock].self, from: data)

            completeOnMain(.success(stocks))
        } catch {
            completeOnMain(.failure(error)) // <-- Unified error handling
        }
    }
}
```

- A [nested function](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID178) is used to do the repeated work of dispatching to the main thread.
- Standard error are used instead of defining custom errors.
- A do/catch and throws are used to handle all the errors at once.

I have one final note: [Async functions should always be async](https://blog.izs.me/2013/08/designing-apis-for-asynchrony). The bad URL error should not call `completion(_:)` directly; use `DispatchQueue.main.async` to make sure the call happens in a later run loop.